# I installed opencv using vcpkg, but I can't find tracking.hpp

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, vcpkg, tracker

I installed opencv using vcpkg, but I can't find tracking.hpp.
I installed opencv using vcpkg, but I can't find tracking.hpp.
The error looks like the image below.
When you install opencv with vcpkg, do you know where it is installed?
What can I do to fix the error below?

[image: tracker]

Thank you.

Comment: check the version of what you installed there.

Comment: Look in the `vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\opencv2` folder.